# Mongodb not running on Ubuntu, no idea why

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

Problem is pretty self-explanatory - can't get MongoDB to start, and nothing is logging anything anywhere so I can figure out what's going on:

```
[10:10:23][root@my-server:~]$ start mongodb
mongodb stop/waiting
[10:10:28][root@my-server:~]$ ls /var/log/mongodb
[10:10:34][root@my-server:~]$ ls /var/lib/mongodb
[10:10:39][root@my-server:~]$
```

As you can see, mongodb immediately goes to stop/waiting, and doesn't log anything to /var/log/mongodb.  There's nothing in /var/lib/mongodb either.  There's nothing useful in `/var/log/upstart` either.  Where can I look for information on what the heck upstart is doing, and why it can't seem to start MongoDB?

Comment: Can you try running it without the service, just in teminal run `mongod` or `mongodb` also check `sudo netstat -lpn |grep :27017` or `ps aux | grep mongod` to see if something is already running on that port or if mongodb is already running

Comment: There are no existing mongo processes running.  I can start it manually with mongod, but that's not super helpful on its own.

Comment: Ok so it starts manually just fine? Are you using the init script that came with MongoDB when you installed it? Have you modified the script?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "init script".  It's an upstart job, so `/etc/init.d/mongodb` is a symlink to `/lib/init/upstart-job`.  Near as I can tell, the problem is actually that the `mongodb-10gen` package is somehow incompatible with upstart, because that package doesn't create a `/usr/bin/mongodb` executable for upstart to run.  Sigh.

Comment: It should be making a `/etc/init/mongodb.conf` file which upstart will use to launch mongodb, the symlink is something completely different to whether it has a upstart job or not

Comment: Also it should be `sudo service mongodb start` not `start mongodb`

Comment: The startup message for `/etc/init.d/mongdb start` very explicitly says that `start mongodb` is a valid method for starting the service.  I don't know why Ubuntu has decided to provide so many ways of starting services, but there it is.  *shrug*

Comment: Hmm that is weird, I never actually knew that, it always told me to use service instead but anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question with another question: [Mongo does not run when installed via mongodb-10gen package on Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417954/mongodb-10gen-package-on-ubuntu-12-04).  In this case, the `mongodb-10gen` package doesn't seem to be installing the right executables for upstart to use, and upstart helpfully doesn't log anything when the executable it expects to be present isn't there.  So I've asked a followup question about what the deal with the 10gen package is.