# Mongo does not run when installed via mongodb-10gen package on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

So I've followed the Mongodb installation instructions here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/.  However, after installing, mongodb does not run when invoked with `start mongodb` or `/etc/init.d/mongodb start`.  After digging around and adding debug comments to `/lib/init/upstart` (!) I deduced that the problem is that the `mongodb-10gen` package inexplicably doesn't create an `/usr/bin/mongodb` executable for upstart to reference - it creates a bunch of other executables, but not that one.  What's going on?  Is the 10gen package broken?  Are the instructions wrong?  Or is something really, really, really bizarre going on on my system?

P.S. Installing the `mongodb` package included with Ubuntu 12.04 works like a charm.

Comment: The one that "comes" with Ubuntu 12.04 is the repo edition, the one that page describes installing...I don't understand what your doing, where did you get the `mongodb-10gen` package from? Cos if you got it from the repos it is the same one that comes included with Ubuntu as you say

Comment: That `mongodb-10gen` is very explicitly described on the link I referenced.  It doesn't say anything about the package being incompatible with upstart, so I'm wondering what I'm missing about why it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Ok I had a misconception about 10gens usage of repos for a second, ok so the ubuntu repo list works but the 10gen doesn't. Hmmm, I'll test this out for myself in a second

Comment: Curious: Why are you using a different start technique than documented? I just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 12.04 and followed the instructions, and mongodb starts as a service successfully using `sudo service mongodb start`

Comment: @WiredPrairie `start mongodb` does work as well and `/etc/init.d/mongodb` is of course the old way of doing it pre-upstart. Little known documented method of running a upstart job is that method as I have just found out myself.

Comment: Well, for whatever reason, it does seem to work as expected on a fresh install - no idea what's gone wrong with the system I was working with before where reinstalling the package just didn't work right.  You can blame the Ubuntu people for creating yet more startup incantations.

Comment: I have the same problem.Before Ｉ install mongodb-10gen, I just use mongodb from the ubunbtu official repo.Every thing is OK.But that version is too old. so today I switch to mongodb-10gen.Then problem occurs.

Comment: did you "apt-get install mongodb-10gen=2.2.3" or "apt-get install mongodb-10gen"?

Answer (score 0):

Is there mongod executable?

If there is correct config in /etc/conf.d/mongod.conf or /etc/mongo/mongod.conf or something similar, you may start server by running mongod -f /etc/mongo/mongod.conf.

If there is no correct config, just write it by yourself. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

[My config](http://pastebin.com/mYG7m1UL).

Also, if there is error with missing /usr/bin/mongodb, you may just create symlink from /usr/bin/mongodb to /usr/bin/mongod by executing following (with root privileges):

```
# ln -s /usr/bin/mongod /usr/bin/mongodb
```